# Explode a column vertically top create new columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe like this :

```
name    zones
aa  []
bb  [{"rack":11,"bin":22},{"rack":33,"bin":44}]
```

Now I want to transform into something like this:

```
name    rack    bin
aa  -   -
bb  11  22
bb  33  44
```

I tried this:

cols = ['zones',]

df1 = (df.drop(cols, axis=1)
.join(pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(df[x].explode()).add_prefix(f'{x}.')
for x in cols], axis=1)))

But it only gives the values of first dictionary:

```
name  zones.rack  zones.bin
0   aa         NaN        NaN
1   bb        11.0       22.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) before converting to columns with [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) and joining:

```
out = df.explode('zones', ignore_index=True)
out = out.join(pd.json_normalize(out.pop('zones')).add_prefix('zones.'))
```

*NB. add `.fillna('-')` if you want to fill the NaNs with `'-'`.*

Output:

```
  name  zones.rack  zones.bin
0   aa         NaN        NaN
1   bb        11.0       22.0
2   bb        33.0       44.0
```

If you have more than one column to handle, use a loop and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
cols = ['zones', 'zones2']

out = df2.explode(cols, ignore_index=True)
out = out.join(pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(out.pop(col))
                            .add_prefix(f'{col}.')
                          for col in cols
                         ], axis=1)
              )
```

Example if there was a column `zones2`:

```
  name  zones.rack  zones.bin  zones2.rack  zones2.bin
0   aa         NaN        NaN          NaN         NaN
1   bb        11.0       22.0         11.0        22.0
2   bb        33.0       44.0         33.0        44.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need create indices by Series created in [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) after [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
cols = ['zones',]

dfs = []
for x in cols:
    s = df[x].explode()
    df1 = pd.json_normalize(s).set_index(s.index).add_prefix(f'{x}.')
    dfs.append(df1)

df1 = df.drop(cols, axis=1).join(pd.concat(dfs, axis=1))
print (df1)
  name  zones.rack  zones.bin
0   aa         NaN        NaN
1   bb        11.0       22.0
1   bb        33.0       44.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option :

```
out = (
    df.join(df.pop("zones").explode().dropna()
         .apply(lambda x: pd.Series({k: v for k,v in x.items()})))
         .fillna("-") #this chain is optional though
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

  names  rack   bin
0    aa     -     -
1    bb 11.00 22.00
1    bb 33.00 44.00
```